# Chrome downloading pages rather than loading them

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason recently Chrome began downloading specific pages rather than attempting to render them. But it isn't actually downloading the page, instead it's saving off some sort of error message:

```
00000000: 0000 1204 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 0a00  ................
00000010: 0400 00ff ff00 0500 0040 0000 0004 0800  .........@......
00000020: 0000 0000 000f 0001 0000 1e07 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0168 7474 7032 5f68  .........http2_h
00000040: 616e 6473 6861 6b65 5f66 6169 6c65 64    andshake_failed
```

One page I'm having problems with is www.virustotal.com.

- This doesn't appear to be very widespread; I've really only been able to solidly identify VirusTotal.
- The same behavior persists in Incognito mode, as well as with all extras disabled.
- This does not happen in other browsers.
- I am behind a proxy (I do not have access to the proxy, but I am close with the people who do). I do not believe the proxy supports HTTP2, but this is a recent change in behavior and nobody else I know behind our proxy that uses this site with Chrome is experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an internal proxy error. Apparently VirusTotal and Chrome are forcing HTTP2, a protocol that our corporate proxies do not support natively at this time.